# Query String from database in java with apostrophe

Tags: java, mysql, sql

how do i query string  in java program with apostrophe?

example:

if i had a name `M'lang` stored in database

i had a method

```
getName(String name){
    ----code for querying----
}
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use a PreparedStatement (always a good idea anyway), and pass the string as a parameter.

example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name=?");
stmt.setString(1, "M'lang");
...
```